# Time stored on table is greater than now

Tags: php, mysql

I have this weird situation.

I'm trying to convert my time stored on a table to *time-ago* format.
It's working well on my localhost, but not on the server.

For some reason, when calculating the difference between the now and the time on the server, I receive a negative number.

Here is an example:

```
$time = '2015-01-02 05:52:49'; //Time that is stored on the created cell
$now = time();
$seconds = strtotime($time);

$difference = $now - $seconds;
```

The output for the above code is `-13628`.

Timezone is set to `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: probably because you saved those fields on localhost and you are working with them on a remote server

Comment: You have error reporting on? `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Are any errors showing?

Comment: @slash197 - No, I'm fetching the time from the table. The above code is just an example of the output that I receive from the server.

Comment: @Darren I don't have any errors to show about this. It's not a syntax thing, but probably something with the logic of and code or misconfiguration.

Comment: Following up on slash197's comment, to compare "apples to apples" when it comes to time, your best bet is to normalize all your times to UTC. When you retrieve time from any machine or OS, immediate translate to UTC. And when you save to somewhere, like your database, save it in its UTC transformed value. This way, no matter where your machine is located, you'll be comparing values that occurred as if they all happened in UTC.

Comment: @maurice But as I mentioned, I set `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` whenever I initiate the code. Isn't that the same?

Comment: @Amitay - isn't time() bound to the OS time (UTC based), while strtotime() is bound to the default timezone?

Comment: @maurice Maybe. I'm not sure what is bound to what. But I solved this by wetting the timezzone to _UTC_ instead of _America/New_York_.

Comment: Here's the [php time page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

So, the problem was that I've set the timezone to `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`.

To solve this, I changes this to `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

And now it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

if the date/time you run this is before '2015-01-02 05:52:49' then the - sign is logical. Try use this instead:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime('2015-01-02 05:52:49');
$now = $date1->getTimestamp();
$seconds = $date2->getTimestamp();
$difference = $now - $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

User following code 
**date_default_timezone_set('UTC'):**

instead of 
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

Comment: You're 5 minutes late :)